# How to allow only subnet for port with iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ip

What i am trying to do is to DROP any packets to specific UDP port, except those one from my secured subnet 10.8.0.0/24.

```
iptables -t nat -A --src 10.8.0.0/24 -p udp --destination-port 63210 -j ACCEPT
```

I get this error: `Bad argument: 10.8.0.0/24`

I don't understand why this does not work...

- Why this command says IP is bad argument?
- How to DROP any other packets, outside subnet?
- Should i use NAT table?
- How to achieve this?

I've found solution like this:

**UPDATE**

```
iptables -N xchain
iptables -A xchain --source 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A xchain -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 63210 -j xchain
```

After applying this, i cannot access port from ANY ip...

**PROBLEM**
I have OpenVPN server set on tun0 interface, forwarding packets to eth0 like this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 \
         -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
         -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 \
          -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Question is, how to catch tun0 traffic and filter it, instead of eth0, where IPs getting real.

Comment: There's not enough information here. What do you mean that the first command "does not work"?  Please edit your question to show the error message, and tell us what traffic passes that shouldn't, or doesn't pass that should.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first example you are using "--src" which is incorrect swich, you should either use --source or -s.

In second example, you are creating new chain named "xchain", and you are filtering packets there. But, if you don't point packets from other chains to go traverse xchain, those filters will never get matched.

Also, you've send packets from INPUT chain to xchain:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -j xchain
```

This rule will only send packets whose destination is the host running the iptables to xchain. If your host is a router for network, you should also send packets from FILTER chain:

```
# iptables -I FILTER -j xchain
```

Note: I've changed your -A to -I, which puts rule at the top of the rule list, which means it will most certainly get traversed.